# Movement of a draggable element

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

If I drag an element for 200 px does it move pixel by pixel?For example if I have a  left of 200 px and I move the mouse of 200 px to drag the element, his left will change pixel by pixel to arrive to 400 px?

Comment: is that what you looking for https://greensock.com/draggable , http://codepen.io/El-Oz/pen/oxrjPa

Comment: I have already done something like that but my problem is this: if you move very fast the mouse,onmousemove event is triggered a low number of times.This means that if I move the mouse very fast for 200px and for example onmousemove event is triggered one time when it moved 3px and one time when it moved 200px the div will be moved of 187 px in one time and animation won't be smooth...

Comment: How this problem could be fixed?In jquery method for drag and drop how this problem is fixed?

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: My code is not useful.My ask is:for example in jquery drag and drop do divs move pixel by pixel?If yes,what is the event that is triggered to refresh divs' position?

Comment: So how can i debug your code? by guessing?! what is the pixel to pixel? and what is the meaning of refresh div's position? if you don't want to help to get resolve for your problem, don't expect someone will help you ...

Comment: I have done the same thing of the example you have posted before so we can refer to that code

Comment: The problem is also in that example

Comment: When you move with your mouse on the image,the onmousemove event is fired.Moving the mouse fast for 200px on mousemove event is not fired 200 times but less...in your example you set div's position every time mousemove is fired so if I have moved the mouse for 200px and the event is fired three times it means that the div moves of 200 px jerky and not smoothly because it is not moved px by px...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a browser problem more than anything. I'd suggest trying to use different pre-set snippets of code for drag and drop stuff and see which ones play nicer with the browser you're working with.

Comment: In this fiddle if you move the mouse fast over all the red div how many time "moved" is printed in console?It should be printed 200 times...

https://jsfiddle.net/n4mo27bu/